# The USB capacity displayed in the machine is larger than the actual capacity of the USB

Tags: windows, usb

I have a USB, when plugged into the machine, it shows a larger capacity than the actual capacity that the USB has.
I have an old USB with a capacity of 4GB, however, when I plug it into the computer, its capacity has increased to 8GB. This is quite difficult for me to use that USB. And I wish there is a solution to fix this, return my USB to its original capacity
Is there any way to restore the USB to its original state?

Comment: Please be more specific.  First of all, I am assuming by "a USB" you mean a USB flash drive?  Be aware that MANY of the USB flash drives on the market have faked their size in the firmware (a scam).  Please tell us more information on what the drive has printed on it vs what is showing up when you plug it in.  Chances are that this drive is simply a fake.

Comment: Also, most 4gb or even 8gb is worth less than 5 USD.  Why go through all of this trouble?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - not even that these days. I went in search of a 16GB stick in my local supermarket just this week & the smallest they had was 32GB. I got three in a pack for £15 [SanDisk, not mickey mouse]

Comment: @Señor CMasMas They were purchased 13 years ago, they contain quite a lot of important data for me at this time

Comment: @Tetsujin And I'm using one like that, however, there are some things that hard to be changed

Comment: TrHH - **Golden Rule**. Never store the only copy of any data in only one location - most especially something so prone to sudden catastrophic failure as a USB stick/SD card. You're just waiting for the shoe to drop. It's an accident waiting to happen. The sword of Damocles writ large above you.